# Is there a natural topology on the set of open sets ?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Given a topological space $(X,\mathcal{O})$ can one assign a natural topology to $\mathcal{O}$  such that

1) The intersection of a compact set of open sets is again open,

2) The maps $\cap,\cup:\mathcal{O}^2\rightarrow \mathcal{O}$ are continuous,

3) For any continuous map $f: (X,\mathcal{O})\rightarrow (X',\mathcal{O}')$ is the induced map
$f^{-1}: \mathcal{O}'\rightarrow \mathcal{O}$ also continuous?

Since these properties would allow taking the discrete topology and I am looking for a more interesting one let me also add:

4) For $X=\mathbb{R}$ the subset $\{]a,b[|a\le b\}$ of intervals has the topology coming from $\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2| a\le b\}/\Delta \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I don't understand 4). Which sets of intervalls are open?

Comment: In any case, have you tried the compact-open topology on $\mathcal{O}(X) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(X,S)$, where $S$ is the Sierpinski space?

Comment: 4 should just say that a open interval is given by a pair of numbers $a\le b$ such that $]a,a[$ and $]b,b[$ give the same interval (the empty one). So we get a bijection between the two spaces in 4), which should be a homeomorphism.

Comment: Have you seen http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20738/does-the-set-of-open-sets-in-a-topological-space-have-a-topology-itself ?

Comment: @Martin: ...so in topology $\mathcal{O}(X)\cong\mathrm{Hom}(X,S)$ while in algebraic geometry we have $\mathcal{O}(X)\cong\mathrm{Hom}(X,\mathbb{A}^1)$...   (just kidding  :) )

Comment: @ Gjergji & Martin: OK I will check whether the suggested topology has the desired properties.

Comment: 4) seems to be a problem. By definition of the compact open topology the following system indexed over closed intervals $[a,b]$ is a subbasis: 

$\\{(a',b')|[a,b]\subset (a',b')\\}_{[a,b]}$.

Especially for any open set $U\subset \mathcal{O}$ we can find a $r$ such that $(-R,R)\in U$ for $R>r$. Hence the compact open topology on $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{R})$ is not Hausdorff and  not the quotient topology as in 4).

Concerning 2 & 3. Basically they would follow from usual properties of the compact open topology (for CGHaus-Spaces). But $S$ is not CGHaus.

Comment: I would try the Vietoris topology (generated by the sets $\mathscr V(U_1,...,U_n):=\{V\subseteq\bigcup_iU_i\mid\forall i\ V\cap U_i\ne\varnothing\}$)